# Templating if else endif php

Tags: php, regex, templating

I made this failure regex to match if block for templating purpose!
my if block is

```
{if username == 'admin'}
  Hello Admin
{else}
  Hello visitor
{endif}
```

Or

```
{if pagetitle == 'about'}
   We are so and so!
{endif}
```

{else} block is optional tho!

my failed regex is

```
$pattern = '@\{if\s+(.*?)\}(.*?)(\{else\}(.*?))?\{endif\}@si';
```

My regex merge {else} with 'Hello visitor' I could not split them!
Please help in this regex to handle the above {if} blocks!

Comment: Ok what is your question? http://regex101.com/r/eJ6cH4/1

Comment: Are you trying to parse nested structures, e.g. `{if foo} {if bar} {endif} {endif}`? While this is possible with [recursive patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php), I'd recommend writing a full parser instead. Regular expressions are just not very powerful when dealing with that kind of structure.

Comment: To fix my regex or recommend me a regex that would handle my if block!

Comment: @p.s.w.g, yes, but my block are {if foo} bat {else} bar {endif} or {if foo} bar {endif}

Comment: @meYnot as hwnd pointed in the first comment, everything is working fine. Can you post what is the problem?

Comment: @meYnot I posted an answer to get `{else}` and  `Hello Visitor`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get {else} and hello visitor splitted up you can use this regex:

```
\{if\s+(.*?)\}(.*?)(?:(\{else\})(.*?))?\{endif\}
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/eJ6cH4/2)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [4-23]  `username == 'admin'`
2.  [24-39] `
  Hello Admin
`
3.  [39-45] `{else}`
4.  [45-62] `
  Hello visitor
`
```

Comment: Just for the record @Fede your help is appreciated and I did some modification to remove spaces and '{else}' so it would be 
\{if\s+(.*?)\}\s+(.*?)\s+(?:\{else\}\s+(.*?)\s+)?\{endif\}